# Coding Style: Assign two different variables on same line to same value

Tags: coding-style

In languages that support the following example:

```
organizationPanel.Enabled = organizationPanel.Visible = OrganizationsSeparateFromUsers;
```

which is better,

doing the assignment on the same line since they are set to the same value

or doing it on separate lines?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Neither is "better" as they are functionally equivalent. I would argue that separate lines are more readable than one line.

ie:

```
organizationPanel.Enabled = OrganizationsSeparateFromUsers;
organizationPanel.Visible = OrganizationsSeparateFromUsers;
```

vs:

```
organizationPanel.Enabled = organizationPanel.Visible = OrganizationsSeparateFromUsers;
```

Answer (score 0):

That depends on the sizes of the variables. In the example you gave the variables have quite long names, and it quickly becomes difficult to read very long lines, so in that case I either would use two separate lines, or would write it out like:

```
organizationPanel.Enabled = 
  organizationPanel.Visible = 
    OrganizationsSeparateFromUsers;
```

With a half your regular size indentation (in this case I used 2 spaces where I would indent 4 for normal indentation) more on each line.

If the variables are very short, it's perfectly clear to put them on one line like:

```
i = j = k = 0
```

Where i, j, and k are used as counters/iterators in a loop and their meaning is obvious.